# Google Play Developer change home currency

Tags: android, google-play, currency

Does anyone know how to change the home currency in Google Play Dev? Our client have made an account ing Google Play and it uses his home currency(not $). But now, he wants to base the price into $ and not his home currency so that other prices for different countries will be based on the $ price.

Is this something that can be done within the settings or elsewhere in the Developer Console.
I will appreciate your help on this.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use just a currency converter to get your home currency value in $, then use that? The price is only set once, it doesn't update automatically as currencies fluxuate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To change your bank account details **to use a different currency, you’ll need to create a new Google Play Developer account** using a different email address. Once you’ve created a new Google Play Developer account, Google's support team can help with transferring your existing apps to your new account. Existing statistics for your apps (including install numbers, ratings, and reviews) will be transferred with your app.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6140453